# Investigate the absolute convergence of the integral

Tags: absolute-convergence

I want to investigate the absolute convergence of integral.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \; x^4 \; \sin(e^{2x}) \; dx$$
I made a replacement
$$t = e^{2x},\; x = \frac{\ln{t}}{2} \\  
\int_{1}^{\infty} \; \frac{\ln^4{t}}{32t} \; \sin{t} \;dt$$
I do not know how to continue. Please, help me

Comment: Even $\int_{1}^{\infty} \; \frac1{32t} \; \sin{t} \;dt$ is not *absolutely* convergent.

Comment: Hint for (non-absolute) convergence: $\sin=-\cos'$ + [Bertrand's integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117806).